# What could change display width?

Tags: c++, formatting, systemc

I have a SystemC function with signature:

```
sc_dt::sc_uint<12> Get()
```

and the lines:

```
  cerr << "[" << hex << setw(3) << setfill('0') << 0 << dec << "]\n";
  cerr << "[" << hex << setw(3) << setfill('0') << Get() << dec << "]\n";
```

result in this output:

```
[000]
[0000]
```

Why does the displayed width change from 3 to 4?

Comment: It depends on what the function `operator<<(std::ostream&, sc_dt::sc_uint<12>)` is defined to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <systemc.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    sc_dt::sc_uint <12> my_uint = 0;
    std::cerr << std::hex << my_uint << std::endl;
}
```

`g++ test.cpp -lsystemc && ./a.out` prints this:

```
        SystemC 2.3.1-Accellera --- Jul 24 2017 21:50:41
        Copyright (c) 1996-2014 by all Contributors,
        ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
0000
```

It is showing four zeros (for 16 bits) instead of three (for 12 bits), as you probably expected it would, because that is how 12-bit integer is implemented in SystemC. And it doesn't get shortened by `std::setw` because it sets the *minimum number* of characters to be written. If there are more characters, then all of them will get written. Also to mention, the `std::dec` in your example does nothing because there are no numbers printed afterwards.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/width/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/

This will print only last 3 characters for lower 12 bits:

```
#include <systemc.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

const unsigned CHARS  = 3;
const unsigned MASK   = (1u << CHARS * 4) -1; // Same as 0xFFF

int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    sc_dt::sc_uint <12> my_uint = 0xABC;
    std::cerr << std::hex
              << std::setw (CHARS) << std::setfill ('0')
              << (my_uint & MASK) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I am confused how that works: `sc_dt::sc_uint< W >::operator &=` returns an `sc_uint<W>&`, so shouldn’t it still have the type `sc_uint<12>` and still print four zeros?

Comment: @DanielH When there is `&` operator in expression, the `sc_dt:sc_uint` is being converted into `uint_type`, which is a just an `unsigned long long`. If there is no `&` operator, then another way of printing is used. See this example: http://ideone.com/4m0BTo. And by the way `operator &=` is not the same as `operator &`, just like there are separate prefix and postfix increment and decrement operators. If you need both, then you must implement both.

Comment: @Sergey B. Thanks for the reply. I do not understand, however, why it is implemented in the way as it is. To print 12 bits in 4 digits is too many in hexa format, too few in binary. Furthermore, why are there more characters, if the value is 0. Concerning std::dec, I have some bad experiences that some nearby outputs may remember the std::hex status.

Comment: @SergeyB. I was looking at `&=` because I didn’t see the `&`, and I didn’t think enough to realize that this was one of the cases where that difference could exist. I should have realized that whatever `&` did, `&=` would need to return the same type to satisfy other conventions.

Comment: @SergeyB. But that was what I meant earlier about the purpose being to convert it to a standard integral type, because those don’t print leading zeroes in hex output.

Comment: @katang I don’t know why they implemented it that way. Presumably they’re *storing* it in sixteen bits, which is four hex digits, but if only 12 of those bits are usable I agree that only 12 should be printed.